# Install4j Run class to perform backup before uninstall

Tags: install4j

I have a Java class that saves a bunch of Java object from a group of Database tables encrypting them and saving to an output file as a backup. The problem I am having is I not sure where to call the Java class from with install4j to be able to perform this task before I do an uninstall of the previous version of the Application. Do I need to do a script or a custom application within instll4j to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the single class or a JAR file with all the required classes on the "Installer->Custom code & Resources" step. Then, add a "Run script" action to the "Uninstallation" screen or the uninstaller. In the script, you can call your classes directly.